# How can i simulate a multilevel map in a phaser 3 scene?

Tags: events, game-physics, phaser-framework, overlap, 2d-games

I'm creating a 2d game with a top-down based camera and i was trying to make a map with more than 1 level. I'm getting a lot of problems when the player has to pass from one level to another.

At the moment the transition from one level to the other would take place through two rectangles positioned at the beginning and at the end of the stairs (which are the only points where the player can change levels).

[image: image of the game]

when the player overlaps these two rectangles the setDepth is modified and I would like that when the player rises to the second level then the first level becomes the subject of collision while when it goes down to the first level it deactivates a collision with the first level and activates with the second. This is what I came up with the idea of doing to create a sort of layer manager

that's the code i did for this:

```
    this.map=this.make.tilemap({
      key: "map",
      tileWidth: 2048,
      tileHeight: 1792,
    });

    this.layer_2=this.map.createLayer("level_2",this.tileset,0,0);
    this.layer_3=this.map.createLayer("level_3",this.tileset,0,0);
```

creating map and layers

```
    this.zone = this.add.zone(256, 455,64,32);
    this.physics.world.enable(this.zone);

    this.zone2 = this.add.zone(256, 391,64,32);
    this.physics.world.enable(this.zone2);

    this.layer_2.setCollisionBetween(1,999);
    this.layer_3.setCollisionBetween(1,999);
```

creating the 2 zone and adding collisions

```
    this.physics.add.overlap(this.player,this.zone,()=>{
      this.physics.world.removeCollider(this.collider1);
      this.player.setDepth(4);
      this.physics.world.colliders.add(this.collider2);
      console.log("zone1");
    });

    this.physics.add.overlap(this.player,this.zone2,()=>{
      this.physics.world.removeCollider(this.collider2);
      this.player.setDepth(6);
      this.physics.world.colliders.add(this.collider1);
      console.log("zone2");
    });
```

adding the overlap events that switch the collision level

All this works really bad because when the player overlap the rectangle i need to wait like 200 iterations or more of the overlap function for the collision with the next layer to be eliminated and the collision with the previous layer added

I would also appreciate any advice on how to improve the logic of all this.

I hope i was clear, and thanks to every one will watch this and maybe answare me. Thank you so much

Comment: Why do you have to switch colliders? Do layer2 and layer3 have overlapping tiles? if not, it is not really necessary to switch? Or is it more a performance issue?

Comment: because i needed to have different colliders for each layer. By the way i found a way to do this. I just stopped using removeCollider and colliders.add() and instead i just created a variable that let me know in wich layer the player is and knowing this i can just controll for the right collider in the update function. I don't know if this is a good way to do this but it just works fine so it's ok for me

Comment: That sound like a good solution, thank you for your feedback. I still don't really understand your issue and why you are using colliders and not using `setCollisionBetween` for the layer's collisions but as long as it works for you all is good. :)